# andengine pathmodifier velocity

Tags: velocity, andengine, sprite

I have the following code for a sprite to follow a path using Andengine. I need to change the speed (velocity) of the sprites moving along the path(). Does anyone know how to vary the velocity along a path?

```
private void follow_path5(final AnimatedSprite tSprite,int i) {
    final Path path = new Path(5)
    .to(20, startY)
    .to(416.0f, startY)
    .to(20.0f, startY)
    .to(416.0f,startY)
    .to(20.0f,startY);

    // Add the proper animation when a waypoint of the path is passed.
    tSprite.registerEntityModifier(new PathModifier(30.0f, path, null, new IPathModifierListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPathStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPathWaypointStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {

            switch(pWaypointIndex) {
            case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3:
                final long[] frameDurations = new long[3];
                Arrays.fill(frameDurations, 500);
                tSprite.animate(frameDurations, 2, 4, true);

                break;

            case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7:
                final long[] frameDurations1 = new long[3];
                Arrays.fill(frameDurations1, 500);
                tSprite.animate(frameDurations1, 5, 7, true);

                break;

            case 8: case 9: case 10: case 11:
                final long[] frameDurations2 = new long[3];
                Arrays.fill(frameDurations2, 500);
                tSprite.animate(frameDurations2, 2, 4, true);

                break;

            case 12: case 13: case 14:
                final long[] frameDurations3 = new long[3];
                Arrays.fill(frameDurations3, 500);
                tSprite.animate(frameDurations3, 5, 7, true);

                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPathWaypointFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPathFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {
        }}));
    scene.attachChild(asprVamp[i]);
}
```

Comment: I did partially solve this by using a runnable() to run another path to move slightly in the negative direction along the path the sprite is travelling at random intervals which works but produces slightly jerky animation

Comment: What a lovely hack, I would never have thought about this :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only give the duraion of the move, 1 per path modifier. So, if you want different speeds at different path points, you'll have to create different path modifiers.

Comment: Thanks you are right I was looking to modifiy the speed along the path but in fact I only need to randomly alter the duration slightly to give the impression of sprites moving at slightly different speeds. sometimes can't see wood for the trees. thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SequenceEntityModifier` to combine different entity modifiers into one, which will fulfill your request since each `PathModifier` can have different time lengths.

```
    Path a = new Path(2).to(0, 0).to(400,0);
    Path b = new Path(2).to(400, 0).to(800, 0);

    IEntityModifier[] modifier = new IEntityModifier[2];
    modifier[0] = new PathModifier(3, a);
    modifier[1] = new new PathModifier(1, b);

    IEntityModifier entMod = new SequenceEntityModifier(modifier);
    entity.registerEntityModifier(entMod);
    scene.attachChild(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution for a similar problem was deriving from the original modifier and adding a factor to the time passed:

```
@Override
public float onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed, IEntity pItem) {
    return super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed*frequency, pItem);
}
```